# Use Schemas from mongoose with Nextjs and mongodb

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, next.js

I recently started working on a project and I'm trying NextJS for the first time for this project.

In the past I have already coded a website with plain ReactJS and used mongoose to connect to my mongodb.

Now for NextJS I can only find explanations and tutorials where the are not using "mongoose" but "mongodb".

I find it quite complicated since you don't have "schemas" like you do in mongoose. (Or am I just missing something)

Is there a way to implement the "mongoose.schema"-Way for the mongodb-module?

Or which of these both ways is the "best-practice" way?

Thanks in advice.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mongodb

They Reference it as mongodb... But they natively use mongoose to facilitate it -> and right down to the schemas... I know what you mean, the documentation is lacking all the parts that make it work... however after watching this video. I was able to see how he made it work .

https://youtu.be/wqhNoDE6pb4  Around 30-35 he starts setting up the mongoose connection.  At 43 he starts working on the schema.

Might be best to just watch the entire flow as you get to see everything that works , then you can try and play with the various features you want to implement once you have something that works bare bones.

Answer (score -1):

1. You create schema

   ```
   import mongoose from 'mongoose';

   var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

   var user = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    email: {type: String, required: true},
    password: {type: String, required: true},

   });

   mongoose.models = {};

   var User = mongoose.model('User', user);

   export default User;
   ```
2. You add your shema to `/api/yourRequest`

   ```
     var user = new User({
       name,
       email,
       password: password,
     });

     var usercreated = await user.save();
   ```
3. If something wrong, you check [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html)

*I find it quite complicated since you don't have "schemas" like you do in mongoose.* - a lot of projects for a test doesn't use mongoose schemas because of complex "pre-thinking". This means you need to "define" all possible params and fields before the real coding. Also problems with nested Schemas and special types.

So, it's possible to use mongoose schemas with no problems if you have defined "project requirements and data structures before"

P.S. imagine you started to develop and fill DB with next mongoose schema:

```
var user = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    email: {type: String, required: true},
    password: {type: String, required: true},
    test: {type: String, required: false}
});
```

and then you notice that `test` must be required as `true`.

In this case you will need to rework all data in your DB where test is `null` otherwise you might have errors with data. This is a simple case of "erroring" but imagine you have other model schema instead of test - this is where your headache begins.